# Why does my background-image stretch only when adding background-repeat: repeat y?

Tags: html, css, image, background-image, repeat

I am trying to have a background image cover the vertical length of the page. When I add background-repeat: repeat-y; the image stretches. When I have background-repeat:no-repeat; it doesn't stretch. What is happening here? I don't want it to stretch, I just want it to repeat until the bottom of the page.

Here is the CSS:

```
  .backgroundTest{
  background-color:white;
  background-image:url(../images/sideBanner.jpg);
  position:absolute;
  background-size:175px 100%; /* I need this, otherwise the background image is too big */
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
}
```

The main issue is I want an image along the left side of the page (width 175 px) with all the content to the right of this image. I'll take any solution!

Answer (score 0):

Use table where you can add contents in one column and image in another column.You can set width of image accordingly

Comment: But then the image doesn't cover the length of the page, since I can't it to repeat this way...and with the responsive nature of my code, in mobile it would just go above the rest of the content.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
 background-size: 100% auto;
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Answer (score 0):

I'd wrap the image in a `<div>` and use the `background-size` CSS property with one of these two values:

`contain`

- Scales the image as large as possible without cropping or stretching the image.

`cover`

- Scales the image as large as possible without stretching the image. If the proportions of the image differ from the element, it is cropped either vertically or horizontally so that no empty space remains.

e.g.

```
.wrapper-container {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 175px;
}

.backgroundTest {
    background-image: url("../images/sideBanner.jpg");
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    background-size: contain;
    background-color: white;
    position: absolute;
}
```